# what portion of US consumer spending that is debt-financed (looking for data source)

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request, debt, consumer-credit

In a [piece from Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/us-economy-credit-card-debt-yolo-consumer-spending-recession-rosenberg-2024-2), we read:

> US households today have a savings rate of just 3.7% — way below the historical levels of 9%. Meanwhile, consumer spending exploded by \$208 billion in the fourth quarter of 2023.
> A recent New York Fed report showed that households added a whopping $212 billion to their debt load over that same time period. **That means over 100% of that increase in consumer spending was financed with debt**, Rosenberg said. (emphasis mine)

It immediately strike me as simply wrong (or misleading at best). Indeed, the figure of 212B of increased debt includes 110B increase in mortgage debt - which clearly not part of "consumer spending".

I am looking for a series that would give us the share of consumer spending that is debt financed, but so far could not find any. In theory we can create one as in the article (but this time substract mortgage debt), but I'm unsure this is a very good approach. As far as I could tell those two figures are from different sources (BEA and NY Fed) so they might not correspond very well in terms of methodology (For example I think personal consumption is seasonally adj while the debt numbers are not)